# Convert list of strings into single string value; exclude all null list members

Tags: apex

I have five string which contains some value
I need to check if any of them contains value if yes then store them in Another string.

Currently I'm doing this like below:

```
List<string> slist = new List<string>();
String s1 = 'abc';
slist.add(s1);
string s2 = 'bcd';
slist.add(s2);
string s3 = 'cde';
slist.add(s3);
string s4 = 'def';
slist.add(s4);
string s5 = 'efg';
slist.add(s4);

string allstirng;
boolean check;
for(String s: slist){
    if(!check){
        allstirng +=',';
    }
    allstirng += s;
    check = false;
}
```

Is there any other better way of doing this.

Comment: Aren't you missing the logic for your 'check' boolean? something like: `String.isNotBlank(s)`. Besides, according to your question, you add your evaluated string to another one only if the first contains a value, but your code stores all the strings regardless of the value they have.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**As of at least 2022 this no longer works as the .remove(null) was undocumented and its use seems to have been** *fixed*

I am a little confused as there are no nulls but, not to mention just create the all string directly (unless you are trying to understand the concept :

```
List<string> slist = new string[]{'abc','bcd','cde','def','efg'};

slist.remove(null);
string allstring = string.join(sList,',');
```

Is a simplified version of your code

Comment: You type faster than me. I was going to post (almost) the same code :D.

Comment: This code throws a fatal error when run in Execute Anonymous: `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`. The `remove` method on the `List` class expects an index integer, not a null. Not sure why this has been upvoted so many times.

Comment: @MatthewSouther - You are correct this no longer works. It did work at the time of posting however. Will update to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

The top upvoted answer here throws a fatal error, as I commented below it. Don't use it.

If you don't expect your list to have any duplicates, you can use the `remove` method of the `Set` class to get rid of specific values:

```
List<String> slist = new List<String>{'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', null, 'def', 'efg'};
Set<String> sset = new Set<String>(slist);
sset.remove(null);
String allstring = String.join(new List<String>(sset), ',');
System.debug(allstring); // abc,bcd,cde,def,efg
```

Otherwise, iterate backwards through your list to remove nulls (or other specific values):

```
List<String> slist = new List<String>{ 'abc', null, 'bcd', 'abc', null, 'def' };
for (Integer i = slist.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (slist[i] == null) {
        slist.remove(i);
    }
}
String allstring = String.join(slist, ',');
System.debug(allstring); // abc,bcd,abc,def
```

Answer (score 1):

Especially for those people who constantly use this solution, please use ready-made methods. This will speed up your work with the code.

```
public List<String> StrToList(String str) {
    List<String> listNew = new List<String>();
    listNew = str.split(',');
    return listNew;
}

public String ListToString(List<String> aList) {
    String allstirng='';
    Boolean check = false;
    for (String s : aList) {
        if (check) allstirng += ',';            
        allstirng += s;
        check = true;
    }
    return allstirng;
}

public String ListToString(List<String> aList) {
    //aList.remove(null);
    String allstring = string.join(aList,',');
    return allstring;
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SFSE. This is what we often call a "code dump" answer - it is of limited value because it does not provide any explanation to the asker or the community. It's also not clear how this answers the question, which has been marked as "solved" for more than five years.